# Which action i have to select in process builder

Tags: process-builder

I am using"Submit for approval" in process builder when Object A record is created. i have created approval proces, but i am confused Which option to choose in process builder. please give me which action i have to select when the record is created situation.

1. A record changes
2. A platform event occurs
3. It’s invoked by another
       process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.A record change process starts when a record is created or updated.
2.An event process starts when a platform event occurs.
3.An invocable process starts when something else, like another process, invokes it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select option 1 - Record Changes as this covers the record being created that needs to trigger the approval process.